# Query a collecion with n number of records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

- I have an collection named as GPS for every second the n number of device connected with server will push the data  to collection.
  sample data

```
 {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5dd2d4f7d092fb70c022c700"),
     "date" : "2019-11-18",
     "altitude" : "0.0",
     "latdegree" : "N",
     "gpspositioning" : "V",
     "positionType" : "GPS",
     "latitude" : "12.900660",
     "range" : null,
     "gsmsignalstrength" : "46",
     "battery" : "87",
     "terminalstatus" : "00000000",
     "longitude" : "80.2347400",
     "satellites" : "0",
     "created" : "2019-11-18 17:29:26.991Z",
     "longdegree" : "E",
     "tumblingtimes" : "0",
     "positionaccuracy" : "52",
     "time" : "17:30:01.000Z",
     "locationDate" : "2019-11-18 17:30:01.000Z",
     "device" : "6005868660"
 }
```

So now I want to query this collection with last update value of each device i.e n number of device as array.for example

```
[
  {
    device:1,
    lat:11,
    long:4111
  },
  {
    device:2,
    lat:11,
    long:4111
  },
  {
    device:3,
    lat:11,
    long:4111
  }
.....n]
```

I have tried with find and $natural its find whole data not last updated data.
How can I do this please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) , try something like. What I am doing here is first sorting the data with the `locationDate`in ascending order([$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) :1) (I guess its the last location timestamp of the device) and then applying group by on-field `device` and then selecting the last data in the pipeline . You can also do `$sort:-1` (sort descending and select the `$first`)

What  does [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) do?

> Returns the value that results from applying an expression to the last
>   document in a group of documents that share the same group by a field.
>   Only meaningful when documents are in a defined order.

```
 db.gps.aggregate(
       [
         { $sort: { locationDate: -1 } },
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$device",
               latitude:{$first: "$latitude"},
               longitude: {$first: "$longitude"},
               lastupdateValue: { $first: "$locationDate" }
             }
         }
       ]
    )
```

OR

```
     db.gps.aggregate(
           [
             { $sort: { locationDate: 1 } },
             {
               $group:
                 {
                   _id: "$device",
                   latitude:{$last: "$latitude"},
                   longitude: {$last: "$longitude"},
                   lastupdateValue: { $last: "$locationDate" }
                 }
             }
           ]
        )
```